# Discrepancy between physical RAM and /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux, memory, ram

I have a system with 8 x 16 GB DIMMs, so 128 GB total.

However, the `MemTotal` reported by `/proc/meminfo` is `131927808 kB`, so `131 GB`

My research suggests that if anything, the meminfo should add up up to *less* than the RAM total.

[Understanding /proc/meminfo file (Analyzing Memory utilization in Linux)](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-proc-meminfo-file-analyzing-memory-utilization-in-linux/)

So Google's calculator reports this sum as `131` (just divided by `1000000`)

https://www.google.com/search?q=131927808+kB+to+GB

If you interpret the `kB` to mean kibibytes it is instead: `135 GB` (worse!)

If you make it Kibibytes to Gibibytes it's `125`

Or Kilobytes to Gigabytes it's `122`

Below are the details. Can anyone help me understand this discrepancy?

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       131927808 kB
MemFree:         3186732 kB
MemAvailable:   99191856 kB
Buffers:         3476036 kB
Cached:         115792344 kB
SwapCached:       120540 kB
Active:         80544652 kB
Inactive:       45017236 kB
Active(anon):   28044884 kB
Inactive(anon):  3127872 kB
Active(file):   52499768 kB
Inactive(file): 41889364 kB
Unevictable:       13040 kB
Mlocked:        584115752720 kB
SwapTotal:       1953788 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Memory capacity in DIMMs is measured in powers of two, so a claimed RAM capacity of “128 giga-something” is 128 GiB which is 134,217,728 kiB. `/proc/meminfo` *also* measures memory in powers of two, so the `MemTotal` value of 131,927,808 can be compared with 134,217,728 and is safely less.

`MemTotal` is the total installed physical memory minus whatever is reserved by the system firmware and the kernel binary. Your boot log should contain a line of the form

```
... [    0.000000] Memory: 32784756K/33435864K available (10252K kernel code, 1243K rwdata, 3324K rodata, 1584K init, 2280K bss, 651108K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

which will indicate exactly how much is reserved by the system (the “reserved” figure) and the kernel binary (the “kernel code” figure).